# Logarithm-Based Sum

Tags: logarithms

Find the value of $x$ satisfying 
$18^{4x-3}=(54\sqrt{2})^{3x-4}$.
The given options are $2,6,3,4$.
I don't know how to do this.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, it is reasonable to just plug in the four options and check if they give a true equality if not.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$18 = 2\cdot3^2, \text { and } 54\sqrt{2}=2^{3/2}\cdot3^3.$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, following Math Lover's hint, $\displaystyle 54\sqrt{2}=18^\frac{3}{2}$, because $54=(3\sqrt{2})^3$ and $18=(3\sqrt{2})^2$.

Therefore, $18^{4x-3}=(18^\frac{3}{2})^{3x-4}$, so $18^{4x-3}=18^{\frac{3}{2}(3x-4)}$.

Taking the base $18$ logarithm of each side gives

$ 4x-3=\frac{3}{2}(3x-4)$

$8x-6=9x-12$

$\boxed{x=6}$.

Comment: When you see problems like this, first try to establish a connection between the bases, then you can turn the problem into something much easier!